# How to load items without increasing the memory?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, json-api

I have made this plugin which gets data from a JSON source and shows it on a custom post type in WordPress. There are 1000 items in the feed and I get a memory error while importing the items. I can't increase the memory limit. How can I import the items?

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Hello_Dolly
 * @version 1.6
 */
/*
Plugin Name: Hello Dolly
Plugin URI: https://wordpress.org/plugins/hello-dolly/
Description: This is not just a plugin, it symbolizes the hope and enthusiasm of an entire generation summed up in two words sung most famously by Louis Armstrong: Hello, Dolly. When activated you will randomly see a lyric from <cite>Hello, Dolly</cite> in the upper right of your admin screen on every page.
Author: Matt Mullenweg
Version: 1.6
Author URI: http://ma.tt/
*/

function get_json() {
    $slices = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://pf.tradetracker.net/?aid=1&type=json&encoding=utf8&fid=251713&categoryType=2&additionalType=2&limit=1000',true));
    create_posttype();
    if ($slices) { 
        foreach ($slices->products as $slice) {
            $ID = $slice->ID;
            $name = $slice->name;
            $currency = $slice->price->currency;
            $amount = $slice->price->amount;
            $URL = $slice->URL;
            $images = $slice->images;
            $description = $slice->description;
        /*  $categories = $slice->categories; */
        /*  $brand = $slice->properties->brand; */
            $producttype = $slice->properties->producttype;
            $deliveryCosts = $slice->properties->deliveryCosts;
            $SKU = $slice->properties->SKU;
            $brand_and_type = $slice->properties->brand_and_type;
            $thumbnailURL = $slice->properties->thumbnailURL;
            $deliveryTime = $slice->properties->deliveryTime;
            $imageURLlarge = $slice->properties->imageURLlarge;
            $categoryURL = $slice->properties->categoryURL;
            $EAN = $slice->properties->EAN;
            $variations = $slice->variations;
            /* Test to see each of them is correct. 
            if ($brand)
                echo $brand."<br>";
            else
                echo "Some error";
            */
            $my_post = array(
                'post_type' => 'products',
                'post_title'    =>  $name,
                'post_content'  => 'This is my content',
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                'post_author'   => 1,
                /* 'post_category' => array(8,39) */
            );

            // Insert the post into the database and return the new post ID
            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post, $wp_error );
        }   
    } 
}


// Our custom post type function
function create_posttype() {

    register_post_type( 'Products',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Products' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products'),
        )
    );
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
add_shortcode( 'display_data', 'get_json' );

?>
```

Error:
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1877

Comment: It would be helpful to include the error, i.e. at what point in the code does it run out of memory, and what is the memory limit?

Comment: Use a streaming parser, like https://github.com/skolodyazhnyy/json-stream

Comment: @ceejayoz: I am new to it. Can you please explain how it would be embedded inside my code?

Comment: @FahadUddin Sample code is provided at the above link

Comment: Why would you need to fetch 1000 items at a time? That's 2.5 MB worth of JSON.

Comment: @miken32: I have to show them on the site. Should I only show items that needs to be on the page?